# Как настроить radiobutton в html?

Tags: html, radiobutton

https://robocode.ucoz.net/index.html

Сейчас переход на страницу https://robocode.ucoz.net/table.html идет независимо от того, нажимает ли посетитель на radiobutton "Я ознакомлен(а) с условиями посещения данного сайта" и потом на Подписать или просто нажимает на Подписать.

Как сделать так, чтобы переход на https://robocode.ucoz.net/table.html был только после выбора radiobutton и нажатия на Подписать?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>ПОДПИСКА о неразглашении сведений, составляющих государственную тайну
</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><img src="images/kpp.jpg" alt="Здесь должно быть фото КПП">
  <img src="images/sovershenno_sekretno.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Здесь должно быть фото Совершенно секретно"></p>
  <h1 align="center">ПОДПИСКА о неразглашении сведений, составляющих государственную тайну</h1>
  <p><font size="2">г. Лего-Сити</font></p>
  <p align="justify">Я, не  имеющий  соответствующего  допуска  к  сведениям,  составляющим  государственную тайну,  в  соответствии  с  ст.  21 Федерального  закона  от 21.07.93 № 5485-1 «О государственной  тайне» даю настоящую подписку в том, что я обязуюсь не разглашать сведения, составляющие государственную тайну, 
ставшие  известными  мне  в   связи  с  помещением сайта подготовки к городскому техническому конкурсу “Космос и мы” www.robocode.ucoz.net, в частности сведения о ракетах, спутниках, марсоходах и луноходах.

Об уголовной ответственности по ст. 283 УК РФ за разглашение сведений,
 составляющих  государственную  тайну,  ставшей  мне  известной  в  связи  с помещением данного сайта я предупрежден.
</p>

   <p><b>Для перехода на страницу конкурса подпишите документ</b></p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="radioButton" value="Подписать">Я ознакомлен(а) с условиями посещения данного сайта</p>
  
<form action="https://robocode.ucoz.net/table.html" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Подписать"></form>
<p><img src="images/kosmodrom.jpg" width="100%" alt="Здесь должно быть фото Космодром"></p>

  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

в этом случае у тебя есть несколько способов чтобы это осуществить первый способ это чтобы ты создала скрип когда открываешь HTML page он отображал Он каждый раз когда войдёт в твою страницу будет отображаться что он должен крикнуть потом продолжить работу Если ты хочешь чтобы каждого компьютера кликнули один раз тебе нужно попрощаться создать один cookies его компьютера чтобы он проверил если есть этот cookies файл просто пропустить его Если хочешь попросить каждый раз просто создавай страницу функцию который будет каждый раз открывается При запросе HTML page Index Page.
 Если хочешь, то я могу написать этот скрипт и отправить тебе.